# Is there any way to attach Appscan source plugin in STS 4?

Tags: spring-tools-4

Is there any way to attach Appscan source plugin in STS 4?

Is it possible to integrate the AppScan Source plugin into STS 4? I've checked the STS marketplace, but it doesn't seem to be available. Is there a way to manually add the AppScan Source plugin to STS for security analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution is based on Eclipse, therefore you can install regular Eclipse plugins and extensions into it in the same way you would install those plugins into a regular Eclipse installation.

I am sure you can find instructions how to install the AppScan plugin into a regular Eclipse installation or an Eclipse based product. Following those instructions should provide you with all you need.

In case there is a problem coming up during the installation process, I would suggest to reach out to the developers of the AppScan source plugin for Eclipse for further help.